# Close MenuItem when using TextField with select with react-window (FixedSizedList)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, react-window

I'm using `<FixedSizeList>` from `react-window` package inside `TextField` with the `select` property.

The issue is that the `onChange` event of the `TextField` doesn't work with `<FixedSizeList>`.

So I tried to invoke the `TextField` `onChange` event by passing a callback to the child row.
The callback is working but it is not acting as the `onChange` event which suppose to close the menu after selection.

Codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fv6wqu?file=/demo.tsx